# How can I speed up the front end of a web application?

Tags: performance, frontend, stability

We have an application that pulls in about 50 records from a database with about 13 data points for each record.  Each record needs to be reviewed for accuracy, sometimes edited, and then 'approved' or 'rejected'.

It seems as if the process of running an approval or rejection takes some time before another approval or rejection can occur (yes this backend could be optimized).

Im looking for techniques or suggestions to make the front end of the application much quicker while the back end continues to process the previous approval or rejection.  This would help speed our team of record reviewers go through each record.

Would a messaging service like RabbitMQ apply here?

All help, links, feedback is appreciated.
-=Vin

Comment: What do you mean by "front end"? The browser, or part of a n-tiered architecture?

Comment: You're not pulling in a lot of data. I mean, if your tables weren't indexed or normalized properly you still wouldn't notice much of a lag selecting just 50 records. You might want to check your network traffic and your server load to see if anything's going on the database server that might slow you down.

Comment: I meant the browser.  A user reviews the records and checks off a Approve or Reject checkbox.  After a few have been checked off they click Submit.  It seems to take a while for those records to update so that the next batch of records can load in.

Answer (score 0):

Tabbed browsing.